# Is there a way to enable/see the coordinates in minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way to be able to see coordinates in Minecraft PE? I've tried various kinds of resource/texture packs, but none of them are working. Any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the world options before you join a world, in a similar place where the player permissions and gamerules (fire spreads, TNT explodes, etc.) are at, you should be able to see a button called "show coordinates?", which when enabled should put coordinates on your screen when you're in that particular world.

Answer (score 1):

Theres no button for coordinates. You have to type this into the chat function: `/gamerule showcoordinates true`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).